# How to add Cross Origin Resource Sharing request headers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, google-chrome, cors

I am building a REST-consumer using React JS, I have build a REST api as the backend service the frontend will be a completly different application. To sepparate the frontend from the backend.

What I am currently struggling with is making a cross origin request from the frontend to the backend. The backend is hosted at *http://localhost:8080* and the frontend react app is hosted at *http://localhost:3000*. When making a request I get the following error on the console:

> Failed to load http://localhost:8080/api/something: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Right now I have fixed this error with a chrome extension to allow CORS: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

But this is just a temporary sollution, I have tried adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header but that does not seem to work.

This my code used to make the request:

```
let Myheaders = new Headers()
Myheaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080/")

let res = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/something", 
{
    method: "get", 
    mode: "cors",
    headers: Myheaders
})
let res1 = await res.json()
```

I have tried adding multiple values for the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* header with *backslash* or without *backslash*, but nothing seems to work.

Anyone run into the same issues and have a sollution for it?

Comment: Your JavaScript cannot give itself permission to access the REST API. The permission must be granted by the REST API. The headers you are trying to add belong on the **response**, not the request.

Comment: Thanks, turned out it was a backend issue. The backend is build in Springboot with Kotlin and with this tutorial it worked on the first try: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: This is a backend issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a backend issue not a frontend
you should allow the cors from the backend and this is depend on the technology that used in the backend

Comment: Well I can make requests from Postman to the backend, so that is all setup correctly.

Comment: @HarryStylesheet — The accepted answer on the duplicate question explains why it works with Postman but not your browser-based JS.

Comment: i have the same problem before 
when the request go from browser its include the domain in its header
but in postman no send any domain in header
i use spring boot in my backend and i do this by adding the 
@Bean
 CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
  CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
  configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://example.com"));
  configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
  .....
  return source;
 } 
to my security configuration

Comment: It is fixed now, I also used Springboot and Kotlin in the backend. This tutorial helped me out: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/. Just at the  @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000") annotions above your REST controller

Comment: its nice but if you to allow CORS on all API you can do by adding the code 
to avoid add the annotation to all your API

Comment: `    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
            }
        };
    }`